# Using conditionals in automake

Tags: c, makefile, automake

I recently switched from using Makefiles to using Automake, and I can't figure out how to write the following simple if statement using automake:

```
DEBUG ?= 1
ifeq (${DEBUG},1)
CXXFLAGS:=$(CXXFLAGS) -g
else
CXXFLAGS:=$(CXXFLAGS) -O3 -DNDEBUG
endif
```

Is this even possible to do if I'm using automake? Since it generates the makefile from automatically, does it make sense writing it in the Makefile template? Or should I try to find some way of adding it the automatically generated Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use such a syntax with Automake.  There is no exact equivalent for the first two lines.

You could do something close using an Automake conditional (see *Usage of Conditionals* in the Automake manual for examples), and set `DEBUG` from `./configure`.
However I see little point in doing that: if you want to change `CXXFLAGS` globally, simply alter this variable in `configure`, not in the `Makefile.am`.

Comment: Do NOT alter CXXFLAGS in your build files.  The user of your package has the right to expect that you will not set CXXFLAGS.  If you must add flags, use AM_CXXFLAGS, but leave CXXFLAGS alone so that the user may set them as desired/needed.